# How to divide column in 2 when having a Dynamic rendered list

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `each` that renders all of the categories in one list.
The thing is, I want to have 2 columns, instead of a single column with all of th categories.
How can I say "there should be 5 categories in each column" when using an each?

```
    <ul class="menu">
        <% @categories.each do |category| %>
            <%= link_to spots_by_category_path(category.id) do %>
            <li><%= category.name %></li>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question? in `@categories` you have two dimensional array?: `[[<Category1>, <Category2>],[<Category 3, Category 4>]]`? What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [in_groups_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of), e.g:

```
<% @categories.in_groups_of(5, false).each do |grouped_categories| %>
  <ul class="menu">
    <% grouped_categories.each do |category| %>
      <%= link_to spots_by_category_path(category.id) do %>
        <li><%= category.name %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

You'll need to add some stylish here to have these list next to each other.

Comment: Great answer. Didn't know this... GREAT. Lets see if I can style it correctly. Thanks a lot.